# Understanding node.js require('fs') vs require('fs').promises;

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I have two methods.

The first one reads a file and writes to that file just as plain text. The second one writes a file as a stream.

In order to get this to work I have had to add fs twice in require.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const fs2 = require('fs');
```

I'm trying to understand the difference and why I need this twice.  But it sems that fs with out the promise doesn't have the ability to use `createWriteStream` and the one without the .promises doesnt have the ability to `writeFile`

```
/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}
```

The second one writes to a file as a stream

```
/**
 * Download file
 * @param {OAuth2Client} authClient An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function downloadFile(authClient) {

    const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
    const fileStream = fs2.createWriteStream("test.txt")
    fileId = FILEID;
    try {
        const file = await service.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            alt: 'media',
        }, {
                responseType: "stream"
            },
            (err, { data }) =>
                data
                    .on('end', () => console.log('onCompleted'))
                    .on('error', (err) => console.log('onError', err))
                    .pipe(fileStream)
        );
    } catch (err) {
        // TODO(developer) - Handle error
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Note this does work, I am just trying to wrap my head around Node.js.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`fs.promises` contains a subset of the interface for what's on `fs`, but with promise-based interfaces instead of plain callback-style interfaces.

Some things which don't translate well to promises or don't have a natural promise-based interface such as `fs.createReadStream()` are only available on `fs`.  Note that `fs.createReadStream()` returns a stream and uses events on the stream, not plain callbacks (which don't translate well to promises).  As such, it's interface remains the same on `fs` and is not duplicated on `fs.promises`.

Many things are available in either with different interfaces:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data, callback);     // plain callback interface
```

or

```
await fs.promises.writeFile(filename, data)    // promise interface
```

Most of the time, I can use only the `fs.promises` interface and do:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
```

But sometimes, you need both and I would do this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
```

**Keep in mind `fs.promises` is not a complete replacement for `fs`.**  It's an alternate (promise-based) interface for some (but not all) of the methods in the `fs` module.

Other interfaces such as `fsp.open()` have been enhanced and converted to promises in the `fs.promises` interface where it now returns a promise that resolves to an object-oriented fileHandle object whereas `fs.open()` just accepts a callback that will be passed a file descriptor.

---

So, my mode of operation is to look in the `fs.promises` interface for what I'm doing.  If it's there, I use it there and use promises with it.

If it's not there, then go back to the `fs` interface for what I need.

---

I would advise you to NOT write code that uses the symbol `fs` for `fs.promises`.  That will confuse people reading or working on your code because they are likely to think that a symbol named `fs` is the `fs` interface.  That's why I use `fs` for the `fs` interface and `fsp` for the `fs.promises` interface in my code.